# Nested For loops simplified

Tags: procedural-programming

In order to avoid a deep set of nested For loops, I came up with this method to do it with one For loop.  The range of each level's For loop counting variable k1, k2, k3,... is 0 to b, and n is the number of nestings that I am replacing with one level. The advantage is for when n is a very large number.  The disadvantage is lack of flexibility on the range of each counting variable.

Here is an example for n = 3 and b = 7:

```
b = 7; n = 3;
For[k = b^3, k < b^4, k++,   
    klist = RealDigits[k, b][[1]]; 
    k1= klist[[2]];
    k2 = klist[[3]];
    k3 = klist[[4]];
 (*  the rest of the code is here... *) ]
```

Does anyone know of other ways to flatten nested For loops?

Comment: What does $n$ have to do with anything?

Comment: A simpler way to nest loops is to use Do or Table, both of which accept multiple iterators.

Comment: In the example it should have been k = b^n, not k = b^3.

Comment: For the second comment, can you give an example of a Do or Table with multiple iterators?

Comment: user5922, you can ping other users with @ just like @bills.

Answer (score 1):

*Not an answer but a longer comment.*

It really depends on what `(*  the rest of the code is here... *)` is. Many linear algebraic operations can be applied entirely without `For` constructs via vectorization (for arbitrary depth).

Anyways, `For` is *not* a first-class member of Mathematica. It is there only for compatibility reasons. (Valued by the many question about `For` on this site, it was one of the worst design decisions to include it, IMHO.) Mathematica just works differently. See also [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609)

Usually, what you want to use is indeed `Do` or `Table`. `Do` and `Table` are able to compile their body in certain circumstance which will grant an enormous performance boost. Plus the iterator in `Do` and `Table` is scoped which prevents *a lot* of tedious debugging.

Nonlinear operations can be also "looped" with the help of `Map` and depth specifications. If you really need to access the indices, `MapIndexed` is your friend: Write a function `f` that takes entries of a pre-existing array and its position indices as input and use something as follows:

```
data = Outer[List, Array[a, 2], Array[b, 3], Array[c, 4]];
MapIndexed[{X, i} \[Function] f[X, i], data, {3}]
```

Execute this in a fresh kernel to get an impression of what is happening there.

## Side remark

For-loops are actually also *not* first-class members in C. Because of the flexibility on what you can do with the iterator in the body of a for-loop in C, they are actually very inefficient (compared to Fortran which is more restrictive in that respect). Runtime efficiency is only obtained because the compiler "optimizes away" most for-loops. (In Mathematica lingo, the compiler replaces `For`-loops by `Do`-loops or even by vectorization.)

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to use the form of the Do which in simplest form looks like this:

```
Do[Print[i], {i, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

The iterator can be of any dimension. So for a 2D example:

```
iters = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}};
Do[Print[Total[i]], {i, iters}]
```

So this iterates with i equal to each of the three entries in the list iters. Similarly,

```
iters = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
Do[Print[Total[i]], {i, iters}]
```

this will iterate over all the elements of iters. The Print statement can be replaced by any function (or collection of functions) as long as they can take the vector i as input.

This changes the problem from how to use For (or Do or Table) to one of constructing the list of iteration values. This can be done in many ways, using Range, or Outer, or Array, or whatever is convenient for the particulars of your problem. Table uses exactly the same syntax but builds the output as a vector directly:

```
iters = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
Table[Total[i], {i, iters}]
```